# Can I run DCE (Docker Container Executor) on Yarn with Kerberos?

Tags: hadoop, docker, kerberos, hadoop-yarn

The hadoop documentation states that DCE does not support a cluster with secure mode (Kerberos): https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainerExecutor.html

Are people working on this? Is there a way around this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. There's no current work on DCE ([YARN-2466](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2466)). Efforts have shifted towards supporting Docker containers in the LinuxContainerExecutor ([YARN-3611](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-3611)). This will support Kerberos. There is currently no documentation yet ([YARN-5258](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-5258)) and many of these features are expected to be part of the 2.8 Apache release.

Source and more info:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/39064/can-i-run-dce-docker-container-executor-on-yarn-wi.html